# Ham and beans in a Crock-Pot

Tags: crockpot

I boil my navy beans first and I put in a Crock-Pot with ham that I had Frozen it's already been cooked they have been cooking for about 4 hours on low my question is can I shut the crockpot off for about 5 hours I meant by get back for my appointments can turn it back on low I just don't want to overcook the beans I would appreciate any help you could offer thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether the ham had been defrosted first; if not the temperature would have taken so long to rise that you're already outside the safety guidelines.  Even then, turning off the slow cooker for several hours is a bad idea from a food safety point of view.  The beans shouldn't overcook too much on low anyway, so I'd say just leave it on low.